# I need a command to filter the statements from a .txt file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with the following contents:

```
select *
 from 
emp;


select *
 from
 dept;

selection
end;
```

I want to obtain this output:

```
select *
 from 
emp;


select *
 from
 dept;
```

I tried by using

```
awk '/SELECT/{a=1} a; /;/{a=0}' XXARXADLMT.txt
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your posts. That said, what exactly do you need here? Do you just want to remove the `selection` and `end;` lines? Why are you using `SELECT` in your `awk` example but `select` in the file? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need to do. I did my best to edit and make it clearer but I don't know what you need.

Comment: simplest answer is `head -n -3 XXARXADLMT.txt` (print all but last three lines of the input) but that's almost certainly not what you want - it works only for that exact file.  BTW, IIRC, using a negative number with `head -n` like this requires `head` from GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

This will do even if your file is longer then the one you inserted :

```
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == "select *" ]]; then
    echo "$line"
    read line
    echo "$line"
    read line
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < XXARXADLMT.txt
```

Or you can replace the repeating `read line; echo $line;` with :

```
for i in {1..2}; do read line; echo $line; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, there are two problems in your script:

- case sensitivity,
- matching parts of longer words.

Moreover, instead of setting a variable you can use a comma operator.

Concluding, the following should do what you wanted:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/select /,/;/' XXARXADLMT.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00 -n -e 'print if (m/select /i)' XXARXADLMT.txt
```

This uses `perl`'s paragraph-reading mode (`-00` option) to print only the paragraphs matching the case-insensitive regular expression `select` (with a trailing space).

"paragraphs" are blocks of text separated by 1-or-more blank lines.

Output:

```
select *
 from 
emp;

select *
 from
 dept;
```

(there is another blank line at the end of the output but, due to the vagaries of html and this site's code-formatiing, it isn't being displayed here).