# How to filter the table names from .txt file

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

```
select *
 from 
emp;


select *
 from
 dept;

selection
end;
```

I want to obtain this output:

```
select *
 from 
emp;


select *
 from
 dept;
```

I tried by using:

```
awk '/select/{a=1} a; /;/{a=0}' XXARXADLMT.txt
```

Output:

```
select *
 from 
emp;


select *
 from
 dept;

selection
end;
```

Comment: `awk '/^select /{p=1} /^selection/{p=0}p' file`

Comment: What's the difference between the file and the expected output? The only difference I see is that its last three lines are missing, but it's not clear that this is what you want... Do you want to keep only the select statements?

Comment: For example i said "selection" but the word may contain the letters "select" .. other example i can say as selected this word also contains select.. i need to filter between select.. I don't want the data other then select..

Comment: how is this any different from your previous question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279424/7696?  Don't ask the same question more than once.  If you don't get answers that help you, edit your original question instead.  and add the information that was requested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways to do that. What comes to my head right now is to use `grep` with it's `-B` & `-A` flags

```
$ grep -B 1 -A 1 'from' file.txt
```

If you want the empty line, set the `-A` to 2

Answer (score 0):

As Ziggy says, is not very clear what you need but maybe this AWK will do.

```
awk ' /select \*$/{flag=1;print;next}/selection/{flag=0}flag' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If commands are ended by `;` you could:

```
 awk -v RS=";" '/from/' file
```

If you want just the table names after "from" you can try

```
 perl -0nE 'say join(";", /from\s+(\w+)/ig)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your entries are always separated by exactly one blank line, you can do the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"; FS="\n"; OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n";} {if ($1 ~ /\<select\>/) {print};}' file.txt
```

Input file:

```
select *
 from 
emp;

select *
 from
 dept;

selection
end;

select something
more

selected
wrong

select
again
*
from class;
```

Output:

```
select *
 from 
emp;

select *
 from
 dept;

select something
more

select
again
*
from class;
```

Only those blocks of text having `select` as the exact first word will only be selected.